# relationship for models and show balances to user

Tags: laravel

Hello We have three models (user - currencies - balances) What should be the relationship of these tables, for example, I want to receive the amount of bitcoin currency of user. As the following code:

```
$coin->user->balance;
```

this is coin migration:

```
    Schema::create('coins', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('symbol')->unique();
        $table->decimal('buy_percent',6,4)->nullable();
        $table->enum('buy_status' , ['active' , 'inactive'])->default('inactive');
        $table->text('buy_description')->nullable();
        $table->decimal('sell_percent',6,4)->nullable();
        $table->enum('sell_status' , ['active' , 'inactive'])->default('inactive');
        $table->text('sell_description')->nullable();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

and user :

```
    Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->enum('type', [User::TYPE_ADMIN, User::TYPE_USER])->default(User::TYPE_USER);
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('email')->unique()->nullable();
        $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
        $table->string('password')->nullable();
        $table->timestamp('password_changed_at')->nullable();
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->softDeletes();
    });
```

this is pivot table (i include this in balances migration)

```
        Schema::create('balances', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('coin_id');
            $table->string('symbol');
            $table->decimal('balance');
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
            $table->foreign('coin_id')->references('id')->on('coins');
        });
        Schema::create('coin_user', function(Blueprint $table)
        {
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');
            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');

            $table->unsignedBigInteger('coin_id');
            $table->foreign('coin_id')->references('id')->on('coins')->onDelete('cascade');

            $table->unsignedBigInteger('balance_id');
            $table->foreign('balance_id')->references('id')->on('balances')->onDelete('cascade');
        });
```

and Balances model :

```
    public function coins()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Coin::class , 'balances');
    }

    public function user()
    {
        $this->belongsToMany(User::class , 'balances');
    }
```

Comment: sorry, i'm edited it @TimLewis

Comment: No worries! Can you include your migrations and/or Models for these tables too? Might helps if we can visualize the database columns and relationships (if defined; migration would help define that if they're not)

Comment: i'm include migration bro @TimLewis

Comment: Cool! So this looks like it should be a `many-to-many` (Many Users have Many Coins, and vice-versa, through the `balances` table). Check the documentation for how to set this up: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many (for the set-up), https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#retrieving-intermediate-table-columns for how to handle `symbol` and `balance` columns). With that, you'd be able to do `foreach($coin->users as $balance)`, `$balance->coin` and `$balance->user`, etc etc.

Comment: Can you give a sample code?
So far I have tried all the relationships for this and I have mixed everything up :( @TimLewis

Answer (score 1):

For this type of relationship, you will have 2 Models:

`Coin.php`

```php
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Coin extends Model {
  public function users() {
    return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'balances')->withPivot(['symbol', 'balance']);
}
```

`User.php`

```php
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class User extends Model {
  public function coins() {
    return $this->belongsToMany(Coin::class, 'balances')->withPivot(['symbol', 'balance']);
}
```

Note: You models might be slightly different, the `belongsToMany()` is the important part here.

With this set-up, you'll be able to Check User's balances for their Coins, or a Coin's balances for various Users:

```php
$coin = Coin::with('users')->get();
foreach ($coin as $coin) {
  // $coin here is `BTC`, `ETH`, etc.
  foreach ($coin->users as $user) {
    // $user here is Bob, Mike, etc.
    $user->pivot->balance; // 0.16, etc.
    // Do whatever with `$coin` and `$user`
  }
}
```

Comment: Does it really works? Cause `balances` table has no foreign key

Comment: thanks bro, Should migration change? Because this error is given : `Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'exchange.coin_user' doesn't exist`

Comment: Woops, forgot a key, relationships should be `belongsToMany(User::class, 'balances')`, and `belongsToMany(Coin::class, 'balances')`; it was trying to guess at the pivot table name (hence the `coin_user`), but now it should properly link to the `balances` table

Comment: i create pivot table with name `coin_user` now error `Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'coin_user.symbol' in 'field list'` returned @TimLewis

Comment: Did you add a column to that table like `$table->string('symbol');`? That error is usually pretty self-explanatory; the column is missing...

Comment: yes i add it and i have another column for `coin_id` @TimLewis

Comment: Hmm... Maybe update your question to include the migration for `coin_user` table. Sidenote, you don't need to create that pivot table, you can use the `balances` table, or simply rename `balances` to `coin_user`.

Comment: i included `coin_user` in my question bro @TimLewis

Comment: Oof... That invalidates this answer completely. `belongsToMany()` is not valid with a pivot table between 3 models. Is the `balance_id` table necessary when you are simply using `->decimal('balance')` in `balances` table? i.e. Do you need another table to link these 3 tables when you can simply store the balance as a column? Also, `symbol` is available on `coins`, duplicating it as a column on `balances` is redundant.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236328/discussion-between-johnny-and-tim-lewis).